# How do I print out objects in a vector by overloading the << operator?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, vector, operator-overloading

Ok so I'm confused about all this operator overloading stuff, the syntax is just weird to me and I'm not that great at programming anyway.  So looking around on the internet apparently I think the only way for me to print out objects using `cout <<` is to overload it.  So I have a vector of objects and normally if I just had a regular vector of ints or strings then I'd just use an iterator and go through each one and then dereference it to print out whats in it, but I don't think that technique is working for the objects :-/  Here is what I have so far...help!

```
BarOne.h   //my header file
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class BarOne
{
private:
    string name;
    string type;
    string size;
    vector<BarOne> bar;   //vector of BarOne objects
    vector<BarOne>::iterator it;  //iterator for bar
public:
    BarOne();    //constructor
    void addBottle(string, string, string);  //adds a new bottle to bar
    void revealSpace();
    void printInventory();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const BarOne& b);
};
```

and my implementation looks like:

```
BarOne.cpp    //implementation
#include "BarOne.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



BarOne::BarOne()
{
    //adding 4 default bottles
}


void BarOne::addBottle(string bottleName, string bottleType, string bottleSize)
{
    name = bottleName;
    type = bottleType;
    size = bottleSize;
}


void BarOne::printInventory()
{
    for (it = bar.begin(); it != bar.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const BarOne& b)
{
    os << b.name << "\t\t\t" << b.type << "\t\t\t" << b.size;
    return os;
}
```

so how come when i call printInventory in my main it doesn't do anything? Did I do the overloading wrong? Syntax mistakes?

ok this is the main too:

```
#include "BarOne.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;




int main()
{

    string Tiqo, Peruvian, Wellington, Smooze;
    string vodka;
    string rum;
    string whiskey;
    string small;
    string medium;
    string large;

    //default bottles
    vector<BarOne> bar;   //vector of BarOne objects
    vector<BarOne>::iterator it;  //iterator for bar

    BarOne Inventory;   //BarOne object
    Inventory.addBottle(Tiqo, vodka, large);
    bar.push_back(Inventory);
    Inventory.addBottle(Peruvian, rum, medium);
    bar.push_back(Inventory);
    Inventory.addBottle(Wellington, vodka, large);
    bar.push_back(Inventory);
    Inventory.addBottle(Smooze, whiskey, small);
    bar.push_back(Inventory);
```

^^^thats just a piece of it...the rest is just formatting how things are displayed when the program runs and stuff.  So ok I'll try and separate the classes like someone suggested tho.  AddBottle adds the info for that object in the vector right? it gets the info and then adds it into the variables name, type and size and then its put into the vector "bar". Or no?

Comment: wait what. You have a `vector<BarOne>` in BarOne? Also, did you Debug?

Comment: Your `BarOne` class holds a `vector` of `BarOne` objects? Seems to me you need to rethink your class design.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily wrong to have `BarOne` hold a `vector` of `BarOne`s, as long as this vector is not populated at construction-time of course.

Comment: `addBottle` is inappropriately named, imo, since it doesn't add anything.  That's not the function you're using to add BarOne objects to the vector, is it?  Because it doesn't do that.  Can you show the code in the default constructor?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like you're ever inserting any value into your `bar` collection, so I'm not surprised that `printInventory()` doesn't do anything. It iterates (or better, tries to iterate) over an empty vector.

Comment: If you had tried to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) you would probably have discovered that your problem isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @David First off you never seem to push any objects into `bar` so there won't be anything to print. In addition `addBottle` doesn't seem to actually to anything except overwrite its own elements each time. I suspect you want a new class called `Bottle` and have `addBottle` create and push one into `bar`.

Comment: ok let me add the main then, my bad

Comment: and yes i ran it and it runs fine apparently.  It just doesn't print anything out on the screen from the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show us your `main()` program. That code, together with your class design which confuses bar contents with the bar is causing the behavior you see.

The `operator <<` is actually OK for outputting data of a bottle. But I'm sure that the `BarOne` on which it is called has an empty `bar` vector. Your `addBottle()` doesn't add anything anywhere (in particular not to the contained `bar`). Instead it simply sets the properties (data members) of the outer `BarOne` object.

The origin of that confusion is your class design, where a `BarOne` apparently is intended to serve both as bottle and as bar (which contains bottles).

I suggest you restart and try with separate `Bar`and `Bottle`classes.

BTW: Keeping the iterator you use in local loops as a class member is not a good idea. Sooner or later you will run into reentrancy problems with such approach. Loop iterators should be local variables, preferably scoped to the loop.